# Is there a way to get the order of attributes/fields in an instance?

Tags: java, attributes, field

For the purposes of a generic-style `TableModel` it would be nice to be able to get the attributes of an object. It is apparently possible to get the field names and values using [reflection](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/fields.html). However, is there a way to get these according to the order of declaration? If not, do you know of a workaround that could be used in the above example? I've been thinking along the lines of initializing the `TableModel` with an ordered list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create out own annotation:

```
@interface Order {
  int value();
}
```

and then annotate your fields

```
@Order(1) String field1;
@Order(2) String field2;
...
```

Then you can use reflection

```
Field[] flds = MyClass.getFields();
flds[0].getAnnotation(Order.class)
etc
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered to create an annotation for the fields? The annotation could describe the column index of the field, and the column name.

Comment: Nope I can't say I have. Sounds like a good idea. It would be an unintrusive approach for POJO-style classes.